# How do i replace text that has linebreaks in between it, using c# .net?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, ms-word

I'm trying to replace certain text that is inside curly brackets {{mytext}} in a word document, using c#. But it only works with some of the text.

My word file looks like this:

```
This is a test 
{{3.3 iwanttochangethis}}
```

But when i print it out using the code belov, the text is in multiple lines like this:

```
This is a test 
{{
3.3
i
want
to
change
this
}}
```

Code:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(outputPath, true))
{
var docText = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Text>();

foreach (var text in docText)
{
if (text.Text.Contains("3.3 iwanttochangethis"))
{
text.Text = text.Text.Replace("3.3 iwanttochangethis", "To this");

                }
            }
        }
```

I've tried replacing the linebreaks with \r\n in the code but it didnt work. I've also tried regex using regex expressions:
Code with linebreaks:

```
{{\r\n
1.1\r\n
b\r\n
ygv\r\n
ae\r\n
rkets\r\n
A\r\n
rt\r\n
O\r\n
g\r\n
A\r\n
nvendelse\r\n
}}
```

And regex:

```
string searchText = @"\{\{([\s\S]*?)\}\}";
```

It has not problem finding and replacing text that it does register to be on the same line.

In XML, for everytime there is a new line there is a new of these, just with the line of the text inside: `<w:t xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"></w:t>`

Comment: Depending on the source, it could also be just `\r` or `\n`

Comment: @VDWWD Its OpenXML from word? I sure hope the standard defines the actual uses character sequence.

Comment: In your code is a literal "ReplacementText". What text is actually used?

Comment: I tried using \r alone and also  \n alone. Didnt work. The actual text i need to use instead of "ReplacementText" (now changed to "To this"), is user input. But i'm trying it without user input first

Comment: Just to get the context right. Your replacement text does not have new line characters and after the replace you don't get the new text you replaced it with but the old text still just with additional line breaks?

Comment: The text i need replaced stays the same, nothing changes. The text i need replaced doesn't have a linebreak in the word document but when i print it out using c# it shows linebreaks. I think the linebreaks created out of no where are causing the trouble but i''m not sure

Comment: In OpenXML those linebreaks have potentially no meaning. A real line break would be a XML Tag there. I would suggest looking at the source OpenXML document with notepad (or just any dump texteditor) and get a feel how the xml looks and how your text you want to replace looks there.

Comment: Yes there is a new XML tag for every new line, which i can see when i print out the XML. But i'm still not sure how to fix it.